# Serializing Gson single element array as a simple String

Tags: java, arrays, json, string, gson

I need to know if there is an easier way to serialize a single element Json array as a simple string using Gson.  The requirements I have is this:  I have an object which is an array of strings.  If the array contains only one element, when it gets serialized into JSON, I don't want it represented as an array - I want it represented as a string.  So, for example, if this array contains 2 elements, it should look like this:

```
[
  "Something",
  "Nothing"
]
```

If the array contains only one element, it should be rendered like this:

```
"Something"
```

The code below is a sample class that demonstrates the solution I found.  If you leave all of the code un-commented, you will get a 2 element array correctly rendered in Json.  If you comment out the  following line you will get a single string:

```
testArray.add("Nothing");
```

The problem that I have with this solution is that it seems "clunky".   I have to create a separate object of "Object" to make this work, and this seems unnecessary.  I have also read that it is possible to do this using a custom serializer, but this seems like a lot of code too for such a small thing.  Is there something built-in to Gson (or another library) which can do what I am trying to do?

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;

public class DemoClassSerialize {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object testObject = new Object();

        JsonArray testArray = new JsonArray();
        testArray.add("Something");
        //comment out the next line to test the output when there is only one element in this array
        testArray.add("Nothing");

        if (testArray.size()==1) {
            testObject=testArray.get(0);
        } else {
            testObject=testArray;
        }

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().disableHtmlEscaping().create(); 
        String gsonString=gson.toJson(testObject);
        System.out.println(gsonString);
    }

}
```

Comment: But why? One element array is perfectly valid array

Comment: String gsonString=gson.toJson(testArray.size()==1?testArray.get(0):testArray);